# python seaborn.distplot incorrect legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, density-plot

I'm getting incorrect legends when using different linestyles in seaborn.distplot

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

URL = "https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/WillKoehrsen/Data-Analysis/master/univariate_dist/data/formatted_flights.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(URL, index_col=0)
airlines = df['name'].unique().tolist()

LINE_STYLES = ['solid', 'dashed', 'dashdot', 'dotted']
plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))

plt.title('Histogram of Arrival Days', fontsize=18)
plt.xlabel('Delay (min)', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('Flights', fontsize=18)

for i, airline in enumerate(airlines):
  sns.distplot(df[df['name'] == airline]['arr_delay'], label=airline, bins=int(180/5), 
                    hist=False, kde_kws={'linewidth': 3, 'shade':True, 'linestyle':LINE_STYLES[i%4]})
```

The plot looks like this:
[image]

The legend for Alaska Airlines should be -. (as in American Airline) but it is - (as in United Airline)

Comment: I don't think it is clear why you would expect a different legend than the one you see.  See [mcve].

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Added the link

Comment: Sorry, I can't log into google just to understand the problem. It would be helpful if the problem becomes clear inside the question. Possibly see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest There you go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah I see. So the line is too thick to observe a difference between `solid` and `dashdot`. It would be correct if using e.g. `'linewidth': 1`.

[image]

Alternatively you can create your own linestyle, e.g.

```
LINE_STYLES = ['solid', (0,(3,1)), (0,(4,2,1,2)), 'dotted']
```

[image]